# How to tell which versions of TLS MYSQL (windows) is using?

Tags: windows, mysql, openssl

I have another question about a pair of servers that I cannot turn off TLS 1.0/1.1.   Even though IISCrypto showing them off and made right reg entries.

The servers run an IIS10/PHP7.4/MySQL8 stack.    (I am not the person who set up the server builds - just trying to update it)

Anyway normally for mysql on apache I would add the following to make sure it wasn't using older TLS versions:

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

Well when I go into the MYSQL path I see an SSL folder but there is nothing in it including the openssl config file that I need to update.    From the command prompt I see that ssl is working.   So where is it getting it's config?    Can I inject that config setting into the server settings?

Answer (score 1):

There is so much to unravel in this question ...

> I cannot turn off TLS 1.0/1.1. Even though IISCrypto showing them off

Are you talking about Windows Server, IIS Webservices or a MySQL service? All of those can (read: must) be configured seperately and do not share a config "option" for TLS versions.

> normally for mysql on apache

MySQL *on* apache? The first one is a database server, the second one is a webserver, both can (must) be configures seperately.

> `MinProtocol = TLSv1.2`

This line can go in many places:

- Most linux distros do use a `system_default` section in their native OpenSSL config nowadays.
- This line is also valid for a OpenSSL (linux) MySQL configuration (as long as it is compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher).
- Apache does also has a `SSLProtocol` directive.

From the question I understand you want to connect to a MySQL server on windows. If that is the case, edit your `my.ini` like this:

```
require_secure_transport=true
tls_version=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
ssl-ca=[...]/certs/nfa-ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=[...]/certs/nfa-console-cert.pem
ssl-key=[...]/certs/nfa-console-key.pem
```

If that's not the case, please define (exactly) what you are trying to do.